# Are the Metrons physical or energy beings?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

The Metrons possess great powers, and in "Arena," a Metron appears to Kirk at the close of the episode. It is unclear, though, whether the Metrons are supposed to be physical or energy creatures, though the being's age (1500 Earth years) seems to suggest the latter.

Is there anything in canon which answers this question?

Comment: from what ive seen/read theres nothing to give any proof either way, they could either be similar to the Q were they themselves can control ships, create phsyical bodies for themselves, or they could have extremely advanced tech that allows them to do these things. we know they appear in a phsyical body, but that they were also able to move the enterprise across space with no apparent tech.

Comment: The fact that the Metrons use technology (scanning beams and such) suggests to me that they are physical beings, albeit extremely developed and powerful.

Comment: we dont know if they use technology though thats the issue, they could, like the Q's, simply will something to happen. there is not physical evidence that they are using tech.

Comment: The Enterprise was scanned by some sort of technology, though.

Comment: if they were an energy lifeform they could have simply passed through/over the ship "scanned it" and the sensors of the enterprise picked it up. weve seen this from other energy lifeforms i believe where they mistake a ship scanning then for the life form itself passing over the ship. but again, if they are an energy life form they can create a physical body, and therefore could also have physical tech, so its still a toss up.

Comment: That's fine, but does not the Enterprise think that the scanning is originating in the distant solar system?

Comment: @T-1000: Probably because that's where the Metrons originated. If they were just energy beings coming to pay the *Enterprise* a visit, they'd still have to travel from somewhere, whether that's a place, a dimension, a time, etc..

Comment: @T-1000 "The fact that the Metrons use technology (scanning beams and such) suggests to me that they are physical beings" - Well, [it shouldn't](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Squire_of_Gothos_(episode)).

Comment: Yes, Trelane and his infamous greeting to the Enterprise. Obviously there are exceptions, but the majority of the time, when one thinks of technology, it's being used and developed by physical beings.

Answer (score 2):

The official **StarTrek.com** page for [the Metron race](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/metron) describes them as :

> **An extremely advanced humanoid species** who intervene in Captain Kirk's battle with the Gorn on stardate 3045.6. Being surprised at the
>   mercy Kirk shows to the Gorn, the Metron indicates that in perhaps a
>   thousand years, they will be ready to make contact with the
>   Federation.

---

This is conflicted in the EU novel "[**A Time for War, A Time for Peace**](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/A_Time_for_War,_A_Time_for_Peace)" :

> Nan smiled. This was as big as Sisko—maybe bigger. So much for writing
>   off Starfleet. “Admiral, I would be just as honored to have you
>   available to be consulted, so assuming our respective honors can
>   handle the pressure, I’d say we have us a deal.”
>
> “That’s good to know, Governor. Oh, one thing—out of curiosity, **how
>   did you get the Metrons to actually sign the treaty? They’re energy
>   beings, after all.”** Chuckling, Nan said, “Trade secret, Admiral.”

and in the [Strange New Worlds I](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Strange_New_Worlds_I) story "[**Where I Fell Before My Enemy**](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Where_I_Fell_Before_My_Enemy)", they certainly *appear* to be comprised of energy :

> The Gorn raised his staff, and Dr. Bashir materialized holding a
>   tricorder. Bashir looked around, disoriented. He glanced down at his
>   tricorder, then to Sisko.
>
> “What’s going on, Captain?” he asked.
>
> **Sisko pointed to the brilliant figure phasing in and out of form.
>   “What do you make of that, Doctor?”**
>
> **Bashir was elated. “A Metron.”** He quickly ran the tricorder. After
>   studying the reading he said, “I need a portable transfer pack with a
>   supply generator. There’s too much data here to analyze on a standard
>   tricorder.”
>
> Moments later the equipment appeared at Dr. Bashir’s feet. Bashir
>   stared at the Gorn, then at Sisko. “How’s he doing that?”
>
> “Never mind, Doctor,” Sisko said. “Carry on.”
>
> After several minutes of feeding the tricorder data into the transfer
>   pack, Bashir turned to Sisko.
>
> “He’s dying, Captain,” Bashir said. “And that’s all I can tell
>   you.

Comment: Is Startrek.com canon?

Comment: @T-1000 - It's the officially licensed site for CBS Studios who currently hold the trademark for Star Trek. Basically if they say it, it's canon/